# julia set color mapping

Tags: java, image, algorithm

I am working on julia set in java. Following is my code:

```
public class ColorJulia {


// return number of iterations to check z is in the Julia set of c
static int julia(Complex c, Complex z, int maximumIterations) {
    for (int t = 0; t < maximumIterations; t++) {
        if (z.abs() > 2.0) return t;
        z = z.times(z).plus(c);
    }
    return maximumIterations - 1;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    double real = -0.8;//Double.parseDouble(args[0]);      // a
    double imag = 0.1;//Double.parseDouble(args[1]);      // b
    Complex c = new Complex(real, imag);            // c = a + ib
    double xmin   = -2.0;
    double ymin   = -2.0;
    double width  =  4.0;
    double height =  4.0;

    int n = 512;
    int ITERS  = 256;
    int freq[]=new int[256];

    Arrays.fill(freq, 0);

    Picture picture = new Picture(n, n);


    // read in color map
    Color[] colors = new Color[ITERS];
    for (int t = 0; t < ITERS; t++) 
    {
        int r = t;
        int g = t;
        int b = t;
        colors[t] = new Color(r, g, b);
    }

        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) 
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) 
            {
                double x = xmin + col * width / n;
                double y = ymin + row * height / n;
                Complex z = new Complex(x, y);
                int t = julia(c, z, ITERS);
                freq[t]++;
                Color testPixel = new Color(t,t,t);

                picture.set(col, row, testPixel);
            }
        }

        picture.show();



    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("freq " + i + " = " + freq[i]);
    }        

  }

}
```

Now, I am getting output image as follow:
[image]

How can i get image with better mapping like below image?
[image]

In julia set, i am generating RGB color using return value of iteration. I don't know how to map this colors to get better image.

Comment: try using `t / ITERS` or `255 / ITERS` instead of `t` which depends on the RGB intensity range your pixels are using (not a JAVA coder). You can also remap `t` to color by any gradient mapping this is my favorite: [RGB of visible spectra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214) just linearly interpolate `t` to match the wavelength range ... Also you can crosscheck winth mine [Mandelbrot set I did some years back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44945883/2521214)

Comment: heh a typo the second therm should be `255*t / ITERS` of coarse (too late to edit)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a histogram to see which color values (in which ranges of values) occur how often in your generated image. 
Based on this information you can decide in the color-map to use.

At first glimpse it looks like you only get black and withe. The histogram will show if this is the case.

If you find out that
`julia(Complex c, Complex z, int maximumIterations)`

always return `0` or `ITERS-1` , you need to increase `ITERS` to get more different values.

---

**P.s.**
You can also find lots of color-mapping approaches in the www.
e.g.
 [here](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/juliamandelbrot.html) is an implementation using modulo to cycle through the colors multible times.

Answer (score 0):

First change your parameter. Now for your image it is c= -0.8+0.1*i which is inside period 2 component of Mandelbrto set ( = connected Julia set). On the second image it is disconnected Juli set ( outside Mandelbrot set) smth like : c = -0.800043099666580  +0.164138006668392 i

Second: it is probably the orbit trap algorithm:

- [Malin Christersson](http://www.malinc.se/m/ImageFractals.php)
- [geometric orbit traps by Inigo Quilez](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/ftrapsgeometric/ftrapsgeometric.htm)
- [bitmap orbit traps](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/ftrapsbitmap/ftrapsbitmap.htm)

HTH